# Are propellers obsolete?

Tags: jet-engine, propeller

Now that we have jet engines and all, is there still a use for propeller based flight (besides helicopters)?

Most airlines nowadays don't use propellers, right?

Comment: It depends on what you name a jet engine and what you name a propeller, On a high dilution turbofan, the fan is a propeller in addition of being the first stage of the compressor. Most of the thrust is obtained by the fan-accelerated air which doesn't travel through the engine core. Actual turbojets are not used in commercial aviation (cruising at Mach 0.8) today ([Concorde used turbojets](http://flickriver.com/photos/pt737swa/4908195530/)).

Answer (score 5):

Propellers are not obsolete by any measure.

The jet engine offers two important advantages over propeller aircraft- higher speed and better fuel economy over long range. However, for low speeds and shorter routes, propeller (tuboprop) aircraft are better.

Also, for light GA aircraft, jet aircraft is prohibitively expensive to purchase and maintain. Among other things, the higher speeds associated with jet aircraft make them unsuitable for use in GA. Also, every jet pilot is first trained in propeller aircraft; in fact, airline pilots should have a minimum prior experience before piloting jet aircraft.